# WordPress translate functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know __() this function as double underscore function, some people call translate string.What's the actual name of __(),_e those functions in WordPress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the series of functions like that are for translating strings as you said -- they don't have a specific "name" per-say, that is just the operation they perform. There are quite a few different ones:

- [__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) - Retrieve the translation of `$text`.
- [_e()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/) - Display translated text.
- [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) - Retrieve translated string with gettext context.
- [_ex()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_ex/) - Display translated string with gettext context.
- [_n()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/) - Translates and retrieves the singular or plural form based on the supplied number.
- [_nx()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_nx/) - Translates and retrieves the singular or plural form based on the supplied number, with gettext context.